# What makes Express fall in the category of framework instead of web server?

Tags: javascript, express, frameworks, webserver

I was surprised to see that it's called a framework.  In the MEAN stack acronym, it replaces the web server "(A)pache" and "(I)IS" (e.g. LAMP, WISP, etc.) which are both web servers - not that that's reason to not call it a framework, but can anyone provide clarity as to why it falls into the framework camp?

Comment: Shortened version of excellent answer: because it's not a web server. It provides a framework for using web serving capabilities within node, which is also not a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, **Express isn't a web server**.  It does not have its own web server code. 
 It can either create a standard node.js `http` server for you (when you do `app.listen()` or you can create your own `http` or `https` server and pass it to Express as part of the setup.

Instead, it's a "framework on top of a web server".  It provides a general purpose mechanism for defining routes and middleware, error handlers and template renderers (and other things).

As an indication of this, there are tons of NPM add-ons that plug-in to your web server via the Express middleware or Express routing mechanism or rendering APIs (they plug into the framework in a standard way).   This means of plugging in via a standard mechanism is, in my opinion, what makes it a framework.

So, whereas Apache is actually a web server itself, Express is a layer that runs on top of the web server that is already built into node.js.

It's certainly not a general purpose programming framework, but a very specific type of web server framework.

From WikiPedia's page for "Software framework":

> In computer programming, a software framework is an abstraction in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software. A software framework provides a standard way to build and deploy applications. A software framework is a universal, reusable software environment that provides particular functionality as part of a larger software platform to facilitate development of software applications, products and solutions

Evaluating Express against this definition, it gets checkmarks for all these elements:

```
✔  Abstraction providing generic functionality
✔  can be selectively changed by additional user-written code
✔  thus providing application-specific software
✔  A software framework provides a standard way to build and deploy applications
✔  A software framework is a universal, reusable software environment that provides particular functionality as part of a larger software platform to facilitate development of software applications, products and solutions
```

"applications" in this case is a node.js web server.