# Application Framework vs API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, laravel, express, zend-framework

I've seen the term "Application Framework" used interchangeably with API. I know what an API is and my understanding is that an Application Framework is a collection of APIs.

So, for example:
1. ExpressJS is a collection of APIs for NodeJS.
2. Laravel and Zend are collections of APIs for PHP.
3. Rails is a collection of APIs for Ruby.

Can anyone tell me if I'm wrong with either the conceptual understanding or the examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Some info about the definition of a framework: [What makes Express fall in the category of framework instead of web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502932/what-makes-express-fall-in-the-category-of-framework-instead-of-web-server/49503079#49503079)

Comment: API = allows software to talk to other software or services. Application Framework = software you build other software on top of.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to 1. and 2. because I don't know NodeJS and PHP.

But, it is certain that Rails is *not* a collection of APIs for Ruby. As it says in the header for the [ruby-on-rails tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails):

> Ruby on Rails is an open source full-stack web application framework written in Ruby

As such, it seems that your understanding of 'Application Framework' and/or 'API' is incorrect.

It would be interesting to see an example of where the term "Application Framework" is used interchangeably with "API".

Comment: Hello, I don't have the link on hand (but will search for it). API is "Application Programming Interface", which means an interface to a collection of libraries a developer can use instead of working at a lower level. Can you give me a definition for "Web Application Framework"? I checked Wikipedia and elsewhere but cannot find a clear definition for it. I'm also interested how "Web Application Framework" relates to API.

Comment: "What is an API?", "What is a Web Application Framework?", and "How does 'Web Application Framework' relate to 'API`?" are not, IMO, good questions for Stackoverflow.